# Output voltage of an LED driver

Tags: led

I am looking through the datasheet of this [LED Driver](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/196/Infineon-TLD2311EL-DataSheet-v01_02-EN-1144270.pdf).

There are three OUT pins, the output current can be set to 120mA via I_SET.  I am little bit confused with the output voltage of them.

On page 23 there is this diagram:

[image]

The output voltage will alaways be Vf, except nothing is connected to it then it is Vs.

So Vf will be the forward voltage of all LEDs combined, which are connected to this OUT1 pin?

How does this IC know what the combined Vf will be?

Answer (score 2):

That LED driver has constant current outputs - each output will vary the output voltage as needed to deliver the set current.

The Vf will be set by the LEDs. The forward voltage of an LED depends mainly on the colour and chemistry of the LED, and only slightly on the LED current.

Answer (score 2):

The LED driver supplies a constant current (over some voltage range), and the LEDs 'decide' what voltage they need to pass that current.

Think of a constant voltage supply- the load 'decides' what current it will draw, and the supply produces it (over some range of current).

Comment: Thank you, for your simple but very good answer

Answer (score 2):

The driver IC neither knows nor cares what the forward voltage of the LEDs is.

If you provide a limited current to an LED, then the voltage across the LED is the forward voltage.

The IC you are looking at controls the current to the LEDs.  As long as the sum of the forward voltages for each LED string in less than the supply voltage, the IC will supply the programmed current to the LEDs.

The LEDs determine the voltage, not the driver.

Answer (score 1):

This uses current sensing inside to make a high side current source regulated by some input so then the cathode of LED is connected to ground and  the anode to Vout, it will always be Vf @ Iout.

Caveat (nitty gritty details)

Even the LED has bulk resistance dependent on rated power inversely proportional to power rating, so Vf will rise about 1mV per mA for a 1W LED or 50% less in good LED's.

A 75mW LED is about 15 Ohms at rated current so it would rise more with current, 15mV per mA.

So it is always Vf, but Vf changes with current and near rated current is somewhat linear Rs= 0.25 to 1 /Pmax. Covers a wide range and is responsible for the Vf tolerance you see in datasheets from Rs of diode.